# Cannot serve with SQLJocky (Undefined class 'SHA1' & Other errors)

Tags: mysql, dart, sqljocky

if I try to serve my dart application get these error:

```
Serving `web` on http://localhost:80 [INFO]
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Starting Build [INFO] Updating asset graph completed, took 15ms [WARNING] build_web_compilers|entrypoint on web/main.dart: Unable to read sqljocky|lib/sqljocky.ddc.js, check your console or the `.dart_tool/build/generated/sqljocky/lib/sqljocky.ddc.js.errors` log file. [INFO] Running build completed, took 22.2s [INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 622ms [SEVERE] build_web_compilers|ddc on package:sqljocky/sqljocky.module: Error compiling dartdevc module:sqljocky|lib/sqljocky.ddc.js

    [error] Undefined class 'SHA1'. (package:sqljocky/src/auth/auth_handler.dart, line 24, col 24) [error] Undefined class 'SHA1'. (package:sqljocky/src/auth/auth_handler.dart, line 28, col 20) [error] Undefined class 'SHA1'. (package:sqljocky/src/auth/auth_handler.dart, line 32, col 20) [error] Invalid override. The type of 'ConnectionPool._removeConnection' ('(_Connection) → dynamic') isn't a subtype of '_ConnectionHelpers._removeConnection' ('(dynamic) → dynamic'). (package:sqljocky/src/connection_pool.dart, line 85, col 3) [error] Invalid override. The type of 'ConnectionPool._releaseConnection' ('(_Connection) → dynamic') isn't a subtype of '_ConnectionHelpers._releaseConnection' ('(dynamic) → dynamic'). (package:sqljocky/src/connection_pool.dart, line 89, col 3) [error] Invalid override. The type of 'ConnectionPool._reuseConnection' ('(_Connection) → dynamic') isn't a subtype of '_ConnectionHelpers._reuseConnection' ('(dynamic) → dynamic'). (package:sqljocky/src/connection_pool.dart, line 105, col 3) [error] Invalid override. The type of '_QuitHandler.processResponse' ('(Buffer) → dynamic') isn't a subtype of '_Handler.processResponse' ('(Buffer) → _HandlerResponse'). (package:sqljocky/src/handlers/quit_handler.dart, line 14, col 3) [error] Invalid override. The type of 'Query._releaseConnection' ('(_Connection) → dynamic') isn't a subtype of '_ConnectionHelpers._releaseConnection' ('(dynamic) → dynamic'). (package:sqljocky/src/query.dart, line 170, col 3) [error] Invalid override. The type of 'Query._reuseConnection' ('(_Connection) → dynamic') isn't a subtype of '_ConnectionHelpers._reuseConnection' ('(dynamic) → dynamic'). (package:sqljocky/src/query.dart, line 179, col 3) [error] Invalid override. The type of 'Query._removeConnection' ('(_Connection) → dynamic') isn't a subtype of '_ConnectionHelpers._removeConnection' ('(dynamic) → dynamic'). (package:sqljocky/src/query.dart, line 185, col 3) [error] Invalid override. The type of 'Transaction._releaseConnection' ('(_Connection) → dynamic') isn't a subtype of '_ConnectionHelpers._releaseConnection' ('(dynamic) → dynamic'). (package:sqljocky/src/transaction.dart, line 85, col 3) [error] Invalid override. The type of 'Transaction._reuseConnection' ('(_Connection) → dynamic') isn't a subtype of '_ConnectionHelpers._reuseConnection' ('(dynamic) → dynamic'). (package:sqljocky/src/transaction.dart, line 89, col 3) [error] Invalid override. The type of 'Transaction._removeConnection' ('(_Connection) → dynamic') isn't a subtype of '_ConnectionHelpers._removeConnection' ('(dynamic) → dynamic'). (package:sqljocky/src/transaction.dart, line 93, col 3)

    Please fix all errors before compiling (warnings are okay). }

[SEVERE] Failed after 22.8s
```

I'm not using any function of SQLJocky, these are my imports:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';
import 'package:sqljocky/sqljocky.dart';
import 'package:sqljocky/utils.dart';
import 'package:options_file/options_file.dart';
```

My pubspec.yaml:

```
name: MyDartPage
description: A web app that uses AngularDart Components
# version: 1.0.0
# homepage: https://www.example.com
# author: Mattia <email@example.com>

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.66.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: any
  angular_components: any
  sqljocky: any


dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: any
  build_runner: any
  build_test: any
  build_web_compilers: any
  test: any
```

before it looked like this:

```
name: MyDartPage
description: A web app that uses AngularDart Components
# version: 1.0.0
# homepage: https://www.example.com
# author: Mattia <email@example.com>

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.66.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: ^5.0.0-beta
  angular_components: ^0.9.0-beta
  sqljocky: ^0.14.0

dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^2.0.0-beta
  build_runner: ^0.9.0
  build_test: ^0.10.2
  build_web_compilers: ^0.4.0
  test: ^1.0.0
```

but I had to change it due this errors:

> Because every version of build_runner depends on crypto >=0.9.2 <3.0.0
>   and crypto >=0.9.2 <2.0.1 depends on convert ^1.0.0, every version of
>   build_runner requires convert ^1.0.0 or crypto ^2.0.1. And because
>   build_runner >=0.6.1 depends on convert ^2.0.1 and sqljocky >=0.7.0
>   depends on crypto ^0.9.0, build_runner >=0.6.1 is incompatible with
>   sqljocky >=0.7.0. So, because MyDartPage depends on both sqljocky
>   ^0.14.0 and build_runner ^0.9.0, version solving failed.

My dart version it's:

> Dart VM version: 2.0.0-dev.67.0 (Tue Jul 3 18:17:07 2018 +0200) on
>   "windows_x64"

How can I fix both errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using SQLJocky5 but on Dart 2 I had to make a PR to fix that:
https://github.com/dart-db/sqljocky5/pull/10